# Net 6.0 ignores client SHA-512 RSA certificate when using TLS 1.2

Tags: soap, .net-6.0, tls1.2, sha512

The problem is that the SHA-512 RSA certificate is not being sent in the TLS 1.2 exchange with mutual authentication, while other certificates that are SHA-256 work with no problem.

I have read other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59777145/net-dropping-client-certificate-over-tls-1-2) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904777/c-sharp-and-dotnet-4-7-1-not-adding-custom-certificate-for-tls-1-2-calls) but in those examples the certificates where SHA-1 or MD5 and the answers didn't help me.

This is the [server](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=sifen-test.set.gov.py) I am trying to connect with (I cannot change it).

Here is my code:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(wch.Certificate);

var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
string soapUI = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://ekuatia.set.gov.py/sifen/xsd\">\r\n   <soap:Header/>\r\n   <soap:Body>\r\n      <xsd:rEnviConsRUC>\r\n         <xsd:dId>1584127</xsd:dId>\r\n         <xsd:dRUCCons>80016799</xsd:dRUCCons>\r\n      </xsd:rEnviConsRUC>\r\n   </soap:Body>\r\n</soap:Envelope>";

var mediaType = "application/soap+xml";

var content = new StringContent(soapUI, Encoding.UTF8, mediaType);
var response = httpClient.PostAsync("https://sifen-test.set.gov.py/de/ws/consultas/consulta-ruc.wsdl", content).Result;
```

And this is what I see in Wireshark when I check the exchange:

SHA-256 RSA Certificate, works okay.
[image: SHA-256 RSA Certificate, works okay]

SHA-512 RSA Certificate, doesn't work.
[image: SHA-512 RSA Certificate, doesn't work]

Any help is highly appreciated.

An update, changing protocol to TLS 1.1 also works with SHA-512, but we need to use TLS 1.2.
[image: TLS 1.1 with SHA-512 works okay]